# How to avoid quadratic computation resulting from double 'for loop' when computing distances between vectors

Tags: python, numpy, complexity-theory, distance, quadratic

Given the following code that computes distances between vectors in list 'vect’:

```
import numpy as np
vect=([0.123, 0.345, 0.789], [0.234, 0.456, 0.567],[0.134, 0.246, 0.831])
def kn():
    for j in vect:
        c=np.array(j)
        for z in vect:
            p=np.array(z)
            space = np.linalg.norm(c-p)
            print space
kn()
```

Is there a way to avoid the quadratic complexity that will result from the double ‘for loop’?

Computation as a result of the double for loop (quadratic) ==3X3=9

```
Ideal computation (what I want) should be (3):
[0.123, 0.345, 0.789] and [0.234, 0.456, 0.567] =
[0.123, 0.345, 0.789] and [0.134, 0.246, 0.831] =
[0.234, 0.456, 0.567] and [0.134, 0.246, 0.831] =
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestion(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid duplicate pairs nested loop should go upwards from the index of the outer loop, i.e.:

```
for i, v1 in enumerate(vect):
    for j in xrange(i + 1, len(vect)):
        a = np.array(v1)
        b = np.array(vect[j])
        space = np.linalg.norm(b - a)
        print space
```

Or use a solution provided by the standard library:

```
import itertools

for v1, v2 in itertools.combinations(vect, 2):
    a = np.array(v1)
    b = np.array(v2)
    space = np.linalg.norm(b - a)
    print space
```

Comment: Spot-on mate. your solutions worked like magic. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Others have noted that you can't avoid the quadratic complexity. But if your concern is performance, you can speed things up considerably by using [`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html), which will have all the looping and function calling happen in C, not Python. The following code returns a square, symmetrical array, but it only makes `n *(n-1)/2` calculations:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

pairwise_distances = pdist(vect, metric='euclidean', p=2)
```

If you want a flattened array with only the unique, off-diagonal values, you can use [`scipy.spatial.distance.squareform`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html):

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

pairwise_distances = squareform(pdist(vect, metric='euclidean', p=2))
```

In your case, `pairwise_distances` would be a 3 element long array.

Comment: thanks for the solution and information, they both worked. I prefer the one that involves importing only pdist. Thanks.